# How to convert objects in a matrix to another type?

Tags: angular, algorithm

I have a 2-dimensional array of business objects which I need to convert to their "model" representation (to send to the server later on).

The simplest conversion that comes to my mind is following:

```
private tiles: Array<Array<Tile>>;
...
let tileModels = this.tiles.map(_tiles=>_tiles.map(tile=>tile.generateModel()));
```

This works well if my array is not empty. But in case if there is any null object I got error:

> Cannot read property 'generateModel' of null

I can convert this conversion into something like this:

```
let tileModels = [];
this.tiles.forEach((_tiles) => {
  let row = [];
  _tiles.forEach((tile) => {
    if (tile != undefined) {
      row.push(tile.generateModel());
    }
  });
  tileModels.push(row);
});
```

But I'm wondering if there is an any better approach?

Thanks!

P.S. This is in Angular 10/TS 4.1, but I'd be interested to see tricks that can be done in other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator:

```
tile?.generateModel()
```

To exclude these undefined values from the result, chain a `filter`:

```
this.tiles.map(_tiles=>
    _tiles.map(tile=>tile?.generateModel())
          .filter(Boolean)
)
```

If there is no chance that `generateModel` will return `undefined` then you can first apply the `filter` and then the `map`.

And if you want a one dimensional result, then replace the first `map` with `flatMap`.

Comment: Wouldn't this include `undefined` in the resulting array?

Comment: See addition to answer.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I've tried to use "flatMap", but it says that "Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type 'Tile[][]'". I guess it will if I introduce a separate class (TilesArray) for Tile[] and use TilesArray[] as a type for the 'tiles' field? But I'm not sure if this is even possible...?

Comment: `flatMap` is supported in node 11+. You may need to add `es2019` or `es2019.array` to your `--lib` setting for TypeScript to recognize `flatMap()`.

Answer (score 1):

Apply a filter to the array to ensure you remove all `null` values.

```
const tileModels = this.tiles
  .map(tileGroup=>tileGroup
    .filter(tile=>!!tile)
    .map(tile=>tile.generateModel())
  );
```